# Any Miro-like chart maker, but with global components?

Tags: diagram, synchronization, component-diagram

I'm looking for a tool that works really similar to Miro. Miro is a great tool to create things like charts, sequence diagrams, Domain model diagrams, etc. But I'm looking for a way to also have "global" or synced components.

For example. If you have a diagram of a database, where boxes are tables and the content inside is a description of the table and its fields. And then, you reference the same table on multiple places on your diagram (IOW, you have the same table box visually displayed multiple times on the same diagram). What I need is a way to update only one instance of that "table box", and the changes are synced back to all other instances of the same table box. Much like Figma components work.

I tried using Figma for that, and it kind of works, but it's not easy to use (Miro is easy to use for average people that are not designers, for doing things like connecting boxes together, doing some basic drawings, etc).

Long story short, do someone knows a good diagram tool that works like Miro, but have something similar to Figma components?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Microsoft Visio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/visio/flowchart-software). You can find in internet tons of ready for use components.

Also you can find live version [here](https://office.live.com/start/visio.aspx) (if you have proper subscription)

P.S. No affiliation with Microsoft

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll take it for a spin and will be back to update this question.